# how to give pattern to string in python 3 script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to give a pattern to my strings in a python script.
I mean something like this:

```
x = "hello" + anyString
```

**Note: this `anyString`can be anything even nothing**

**Update:**
at this code, I want to type anything at the end of the string and get the same result

```
userCommand = input("you> ")
if userCommand == "hello":
   print("hi!")
```

result:

```
you> hello
hi!
```

i want to get same result when i type anything else after hello something like this:`hello!`

Comment: Change it to `str(anyString)`, and this should work fine

Comment: Sorry, can't understand what you want to achieve. Doesn't you code work as you expect? Could you provide more detailed example and expected results?

Comment: @cricket_007 it's doesn't work

Comment: And why not? What's the error? What are you expecting to happen that is not?

Comment: But your suggested `x = "hello" + anyString` already works as you describe, right? Maybe you should read [the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/), so you can use a better terminology to describe what you are after.

Comment: MAybe you should work through a https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
userCommand = input("you> ")
if userCommand.startswith("hello"):
   print("hi!")
```